How Do I Provision Multiple Firestore Projects in as Services in Angular 18 using Standalone Components?
I am trying to provision multiple Angularfire Firestore projects as injectable services for my Angular 18 project. Here is my approach:
main.ts
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig.project_1, '[PROJECT_1]')),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig.project_2, '[PROJECT_2]')),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ]
});

project_1.service.ts
export const PROJECT_1 = new InjectionToken < Firestore > ('project_1', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => getFirestore(getApp('[PROJECT_1]'))
});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Project_1Service {

  private firestore = Inject(PROJECT_1);

  public async getData(path: string): Promise < any > {
    const dataRef = collection(this.firestore, path);
    const documents = await getDocs(dataRef);
    return documents;
  }

}

I'm  getting the following error:

Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Okay, I found the answer using this solution from here on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77831155/1079320
My modified solution is as follows:
main.ts
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [{
    importProvidersFrom(AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig.project_1, 'project_1')),
    importProvidersFrom(AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig.project_2, 'project_2')),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()) 
  ]
});

firestore.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class Project_1FirestoreService extends AngularFirestore {};

export const project_1Factory = (platformId: any, zone: NgZone): AngularFirestore => {
    const schedulers = new ɵAngularFireSchedulers(zone);
    const instances = new ɵAppCheckInstances();
    return new AngularFirestore(firebaseConfig.proejct_1, 'project_1', false, null, platformId, zone, schedulers, null, null, {} as AngularFireAuth, null, null, null, null, null, null, instances);
};

export class Project_2FirestoreService extends AngularFirestore {};

export const project_2Factory = (platformId: any, zone: NgZone): AngularFirestore => {
    const schedulers = new ɵAngularFireSchedulers(zone);
    const instances = new ɵAppCheckInstances();
    return new AngularFirestore(firebaseConfig.project_2, 'project_2', false, null, platformId, zone, schedulers, null, null, {} as AngularFireAuth, null, null, null, null, null, null, instances);
};

To use either or both projects in the service in a standalone component, you must inject them like such:
standalone.component.ts
private project_1Firestore: Project_1FirestoreService = inject(Project_1FirestoreService);

this.project_1Firestore.collection('collectionName').doc('docName')... // etc.

